# string as mysql table name

Tags: mysql, sql

The query it self will explain where i'm stuck at, i'm unable to change the schema, is there any way to use the table name that i get from the if statement and continue to query ?

```
SELECT *,IF(user.type = 1,"staff","admin") as "table" FROM user WHERE "table".user_id = user.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/842be4/1

I tried setting a variable, still didn't work out. any ideas ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your structure for admin, user and menu? It is not obvious what the relationship is.

Comment: sorry, there was a little typo, i edited the query, should make sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Not really. If `user.type = 1` then `table  = user` and you have `user.user_id = user.id`. Is there really two field `user.user_id`  and `user.id`?

Comment: @mseifert its on sqlfiddle, should be allot easier. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at my post  - I have updated it (it was an undelete, so it won't show up as a new post).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to have a dynamic query like

```
SET @table_name = (SELECT IF(user.type = 1,"staff","admin") FROM `user`);

SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT * FROM menu LEFT JOIN ", @table_name," ON ", @table_name,".user_id = user.id");
 PREPARE stmt FROM @t1;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: there is a small change in the query actually, i just edited it. Thank you.

Comment: @bro_php, and I edited too. check edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I actually made a typo while typing it, can you check the latest query. Thanks again.

Comment: @bro_php, it's not rocket science. Just follow along the provided answer and make changes accordingly. Hope that make sense.

Comment: @bro_php, that's a separate story and could be because you are doing a INNER JOIN and there is no matching records. Change the `JOIN` in query to `LEFT JOIN` and see. See edited query in answer.

Comment: @bro_php, You just need to add a `LIMIT 1`. Check your modified fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/842be4/5

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/842be4/8 ,, just edited it alttile to suit my needs, works like a charm.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will give you what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN staff on user.id = staff.user_id UNION

SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN admin on user.id = admin.user_id
```

Comment: It returns, #1054 - Unknown column 'table.id' in 'where clause'